# Trying to use abstract data types - How to call the methods through inheritence

Tags: java, abstract-data-type, rational-numbers

I am trying to test my abstract class but I am running into problems when I call the methods from the test class. It has been a while since I used Java and I have not used abstract classes before. Any pointers on where I am going wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.

The abstract class

```
public abstract class RationalNumbers {

    public int numerator, denominator, temp;

    public void setNumerator(int n) {
        numerator = n;
    }

    public void setDenominator(int d) {
        denominator = d;
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public int add() {
        temp = numerator + denominator;
        return temp;
    }

    public int subtract() {
        temp = numerator - denominator;
        return temp;
    }

    public int multiply() {
        temp = numerator * denominator;
        return temp;
    }

    public int divide() {
        temp = numerator / denominator;
        return temp;
    }

   public boolean isEqual() {
        boolean isEqual;
        if (numerator == denominator) {
            isEqual = true;
        } else {
            isEqual = false;
        }
        return isEqual;
    }
}
```

The test class

```
public class testClass extends RationalNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setNumerator(5);
        setDenominator(10);
        System.out.println("Equal: " + isEqual());
        System.out.println("Numerator: " + getNumerator());
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to 1) create a concrete child class of your abstract class, 2) create an object of the concrete class that you can call methods on (here's where you're failing in the code above), and most important 3) re-read the intro-to java-tutorials. There's a lot to relearn, but with diligence and effort, you will succeed.

Comment: Thanks, I will get it figured out eventually ;)

Comment: You will, I'm sure, but don't try to guess at this stuff as it will surely lead to frustration. Reread the tutorials and walk first, then run, then fly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell you this, but your attempt at creating an abstraction for a rational number is wrong in every way.  It is not correct *at all*. None of those methods are correct: add, subtract, multiply, divide, isEqual - all are utterly incorrect.

Wouldn't you want to override `equals()`  - *and* `hashCode()`?  What made you think that `isEqual()` was a good idea?

Look at [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/92symbolic/Rational.java.html) for an example of how to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure what I was doing. The link will answer a lot of the questions for me.